# Bring buttons to front

Tags: android, button, canvas

I have XML files that contain two rows of buttons, one row stays at the top and the other row stays at the bottom. Between the two rows of buttons I have a canvas from the view class.

However when the program is running, the bottom row of buttons doesn't appear. It seems to be covered by the canvas. What can i do in order to bring the bottom row of buttons in front of the canvas? Or how can I limit the height of the canvas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="9dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addbutton"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="9dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textSize="9dip" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="9dip" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout layout;

    static String equation, eqn;

    public static StartDraw sd; //view class

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sd = new StartDraw(this);

        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.addbutton);

        sd.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mainLayout.addView(sd);

        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you do something like this

the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/topLinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/addbutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textSize="9dip" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="9dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textSize="9dip" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/savebutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="9dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middleLinear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomLinear"
        android:layout_below="@id/topLinear">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now in the code you can add the canvas in the middle linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue ,Simple Give weight of 0.97 to canvas ,your buttons will defiantly appear.

you have to set width , height and weight of canvas as follow

suppose canvas is in LinearLayout then

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/canvas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:weight="0.97" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```